# Use jquery to find the first child node with text

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to select the first bit of readable text of an element.

```
<li>
Hello world
</li>
```

and

```
<li>Hello world</li>
```

should read 'Hello world'

```
<li>
<span>Hello Jupiter</span>
What's up?
</li>
```

should read 'Hello Jupiter'

I am having trouble with the whitespaces, so

```
function getTextFromFirstChild(el) {
    return $(el).contents().first().text();
}
```

will return a lf but nothing else (it is the first text node after all)

Answer (score 3):

```
function getTextFromFirstChild(el) {
    return $(el).contents(":not(:empty)").first().text();
}
```

seems to do the trick

Comment: That would seem odd since `.contents()` doesn't accept arguments according to the docs.

Comment: It's also odd since it seems to return "Hello Jupiter\nWhat's up?" in the given example.

Comment: If you have a non empty text node before the `span`, it ignores it and still gives the `span` content. Seems to fail if there are only text nodes too.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
.contents().first().text()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this:

```
function getTextFromFirstChild(el) {
    var result;
    $(el).contents().each(function() {
        if( result = $.trim( $(this).text() ) ) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Loop over the contents, trimming the white space from the text content. If the trimmed content gives a truthy result, it will trigger `return false;` breaking the loop, and returning the result.

Answer (score 0):

I would think the best way to accomplish this is with recursion:

```
function getTextFromFirstChild(el) {
    var ch = $(el).children();
    if (ch.length < 1) return $(el).text();
    alert($(el).html());
    return getTextFromFirstChild(ch[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
$("selector").contents().filter(function() {
    return (this.innerText) ? this.innerText.match(/\S/) : false;
}).first();
```

Comment: That completely ignores text nodes.